# Java jdk - Class path, java home, PATH variables set but javac command does not work

Tags: java, environment-variables, classpath

java -version :

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

javac :

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

echo %path% : (Note: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin)

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin; C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;
```

JAVA HOME is set to:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\
```

Some forum suggested to set "classpath" as :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\src.zip
```

Now, I have restarted my system after making each of these changes but still no luck. All the IDE's requiring Java seem to work fine but javac doesn't work in my command line.

Please help if you now a way around to get it working. 
Thanks

Comment: Is there a javac.exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin?

Comment: Yes, there is a javac.exe

Comment: remove the duplicate C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin in your path and use the JAVA HOME: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

btw if you place yourself in the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin and then run javac does it works?

Comment: There is a wrong space character in the parameter's value before the path "C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin". Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your %path% variable has two classpaths(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin). Remove both paths, Add env variable JAVA_HOME, set it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131" then add "JAVA_HOME\bin" in path variable.

Restart your machine.

For troubleshooting use command "where javac" to see if your env variable set properly.

Yes and there should not be any space between to paths, only ";" is allowed to separate paths.

More details:
your "java -version" is working as expected because  SYM link for java.exe is there in the directory "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;"(which is first path in your path variable)

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is <.....>

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

09/21/2016  06:02 PM    <DIR>          .
09/21/2016  06:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/21/2016  06:02 PM    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe]
09/21/2016  06:02 PM    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe]
09/21/2016  06:02 PM    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaws.exe]
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  18,429,718,528 bytes free

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Turns out the space character was the problem.
Also, I have no idea why echo %path% gives out those many paths, with the jdk path twice. In the environmental variables tab, the path only has about 5 paths.